# How to get an object of a class lower in a class hierarchy

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to get a `JButton` from a `GridLayout` by using a point object (move) using the `getComponentAt()` method. By using the frame of the gridlayout, I can make the following call:

```
JButton button2 = frame.getComponentAt(move);
```

The trouble is these two types are incompatible. The button2 is a JButton, but `frame.getComponentAt(move)` is a component. I get the following error message when I try to compile.

```
incompatible types
found   : java.awt.Component
required: javax.swing.JButton
```

I know these two are from the same class hierarchy, however, and JButton is much lower.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html

How can I get the JButton out of the component so that I can specify this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast your Component to JButton :

```
JButton button2 = (JButton) frame.getComponentAt(move);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if this `Component` is actually a `JButton`, then cast it into a `JButton` if it is:

```
Component c = frame.getComponentAt(move);
if (c instanceof JButton) {
    JButton button2 = (JButton) c; // component is a JButton
} else {
    ...  // component is not a JButton
}
```